# Data not showing in Kendo grid Mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

This becomes a very strange problem to me. from my sp i am returning like

```
 Declare @NewTable as table(ID bigint,
   LoginName nvarchar(500),
   Password nvarchar(200),
   FirstName nvarchar(50),
   MiddleName nvarchar(500),
   LastName nvarchar(500),
   UserPicture Image,
   Address nvarchar(1500),
   City nvarchar(100),
   State nvarchar(100),
   MobileNo nvarchar(50),
   LandLineNo nvarchar(100),
   EmailAddress nvarchar(50),
   DateOfBirth nvarchar(50),
   IsActive bit,
   Country nvarchar(100));
Insert @NewTable EXEC(@Query)
select ID,LoginName,Password,FirstName,MiddleName,LastName,UserPicture,Address,City,IsActive from @NewTable
```

Previously Addresss column written in last so Kendo Grid was showing blank but when i move it in between the Kendo Grid Showing data with adress column as well as.
Now whats happening that due to IsActive column Kendo Grid not showing when i removed IsActive column Kendo grid showing data.

when I adjust **IsActive** column in between **LastName**,**Middlename**  or so on... in my Query then Kendo Grid shows data.
so I believe that data type is not a matter.
This is becoming very tough for me that what actually creating the problem.
For more info Please see the link i posted here but didn't found answer

http://www.kendoui.com/forums/kendo-ui-complete-for-asp-net-mvc/grid/kendo-grid-not-showing-data-due-to-particular-column.aspx#boHoQq6aG2OF1P8AAFTdxQ

Comment: How are you linking the datasource with your data? Can you post that piece of code.

Comment: @ckv :Hi i have posted a link.in that link i have attached image also named as view&Controller.you can see there.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether you are still facing the issue or not, but I discovered, that JavaScript does not support long (Int64) in full. And even if you define your own converter to pass all longs to browser as strings, you will still face issues binding your model to Kendo UI. It looks like there are 3 options:

1. To maintain SID field (string) in parallel to ID (long) and use SID in all front-end activities.
2. To use OData and Web API (I did not try that yet).
3. Not to use longs at all (possibly, unreasonable).